# Why does [$value -lt 10] in shell result in command not found?

Tags: linux, shell

Output 1:

```
Enter your value: 12
./testscript.sh: line 4: 12: command not found
Your value is more than 10
```

Output 2:

```
Enter your value: 5
./testscript.sh: line 4: 12: command not found
Your value is more than 10
```

I need to know what is wrong. My Linux test is just tomorrow:(

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter your value: "
read value
if [$value -lt 10]
then
echo "Your value is less than 10"
else
echo "Your value is more than 10"
fi
```

Comment: `[` is a command name (try `ls /bin/[` — it often exists); it must be separated from the condition by spaces.  The `]` argument must be an argument on its own, separated from the rest of the test condition.  This question must be a duplicate of a few dozen to a few hundred questions — the difficulty, as ever, is finding a good one to use as the reference question.

Comment: `if [ $value -lt 10 ]`

Comment: `[ "$value" -lt 10 ]`, rather; quotes are important.

Comment: ...btw, this is a FAQ -- seen in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_... and throughout SO.

Comment: (also, the syntax of `[ ]` has nothing to do with `if`; `[ ]` can be used without `if`, and `if` can be used without `[ ]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your **if** statement should be as below. A **space** before ']' and space after '['

```
    if [ $value -lt 10 ]
```

**EDIT**

As per the comments

you can always add optional ; at the end of the line. The below script would work fine.

```
a=20;
if [ $a -gt 10 ];
then
echo "true";
else
echo "false";
fi
```

you need to put your condition in the [ condition ]. The below one does not work.

```
   ( condition )
```

It would say **command not found**. As '(' is not  command. where as '[' is a command in order to check a condition

Comment: Another question, if I put a ; at the end. It seems like nothing has changed

    if [ $value -lt 10 ];

Does the ; matter?

Comment: @Matty; that's because the semicolon is optional at the end of a line.  It becomes mandatory if you write `if [ "$value" -lt 10 ]; then echo Hi; else echo Lo; fi` (which can go all on one line).

Comment: you don't need a ; at the end. Why are you trying to add a ;. just curious. Its not necessary.

Comment: I read from some books where they put a ; in one of their examples.
Plus I find it more logical to have a ; in a language, like C#, it makes it look more neat:)
What is the difference between if ( <condition> ) and if [ <condition> ] ?

Comment: If you want to demonstrate something canonically correct, use quotes: `[ "$value" -lt 10 ]`. Otherwise, say, `value` could contain `1 = 1 -o 12`, and it would evaluate to true rather than (correctly) being an error.

Answer (score 2):

And the more appropriate way is to use `[[ ]]` over `[ ]` when in Bash since you can avoid word splitting and pathname expansion with it. Other conditions can be added as well:

```
if [[ ! $value =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    echo "Invalid input."
elif [[ value -lt 10 ]]; then
    echo "Your value is less than 10."
elif [[ value -eq 10 ]]; then
    echo "Your value is 10."
else
    echo "Your value is more than 10."
fi
```

Comment: If using bashisms, why not use `(( ))` instead of `[[ ]]` and get the advantage of more natural syntax (`(( value < 10 ))`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes it's also a good preference.

Answer (score 1):

To throw yet another option into the mix: bash has `(( ... ))` -- *arithmetic* conditions:

```
if (( $value < 10 )); then ...
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

One thing you can do in bash with arithmetic expressions is to drop the `$`.

```
if (( value < 10 )); then
```

This is documented a bit obscurely in [Shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic): "Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax."

This may appeal to aficionados of C-like languages, but it's a bit out of step with the rest of the languages, and it doesn't apply to all variables (such as special paramaters (`$#`) 
and array elements (`${foo[3]}`)).